# Are there any precision approaches that use only GNSS/LAAS?

Tags: gnss, precision-approach

Is there any airport which has a precision instrument approach using only GNSS (augmented with LAAS) for guidance?

Comment: Are RNP approaches precision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FAA has [an FAQ](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/techops/navservices/gnss/faq/laas/) on GBAS (ground-based augmentation of GPS/[GNSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_navigation)). It says they no longer use the term LAAS, instead they now use GBAS to be consistent with ICAO terminology. A GBAS approach is called GLS on the approach charts.

The FAQ has information about where GBAS is used:

> **Where are operational GBAS systems located?**
>
> Currently, two U.S. locations have obtained operational approval for
>   public GBAS use and support revenue airline traffic. These stations
>   are located at Newark Liberty International Airport (EWR) and Houston
>   George Bush Intercontinental Airport (IAH). Internationally, several
>   airports have GBAS and support revenue operations (Bremen and
>   Frankfurt, Germany; Sydney, Australia; Malaga, Spain; Zurich,
>   Switzerland; and 15 Russian locations).

Newark (KEWR) has 5 GLS approaches, Houston (KIAH) has 6. I looked at a couple of the approach plates and they didn't require any additional equipment apart from the GBAS equipment itself. Note that GBAS is not the same as the 'typical' GPS/WAAS combination used for RNAV GPS approaches, and it requires different equipment:

> **Can the same avionics be used for GBAS and WAAS?**
>
> The GBAS and WAAS standards are different and initial avionics and
>   integrations only supported one of the two capabilities. Emerging
>   aircraft integrations can support both services (e.g. A350).

Comment: you wrote "Note that GBAS is not the same as the typical GPS/WAAS combination used for RNAV GPS approaches " ; I am a bit confuse, GPS/WAAS cannot be used for precision approaches right? RNAV approaches using GPS MUST be GBAS to be considered precision approaches, am I right?

Comment: @Ghilardi It depends what you mean by "precision". See [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/29358/62) but it looks like ICAO has a somewhat confusing definition that doesn't include LPV. However, at least in my GA experience, most pilots use "precision" to mean simply "with vertical guidance", which does include LPV.

Comment: yes, I have read it and unfortunately still confuse anyway. I will dig deeper in that. Thank's @Pondlife

Comment: According to the current FAA/ICAO definitions,  GLS (i.e. with GBAS) precision approaches are completely separate from RNAV (with or without SBAS) non-precision approaches. In practice, ILS Cat II/III is a completely different beast from ILS Cat I, and the split between GLS and RNAV looks like it'll be similar if not worse.